# Jquery multidimensional array and chart

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to configure **canvasjs** chart and i need to pass x and y what i get from JSON.

When i try like this, it works:

```
  var parsed = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
  var x = 0;
  var chart = [{x: 1, y: 10}, {x: 2, y: 13}, {x: 3, y: 18}, {x: 4, y: 20}, {x: 5, y: 17},{x: 6, y: 10}, {x: 7, y: 13}, {x: 8, y: 18}, {x: 9, y: 20}, {x: 10, y: 17}]; 

                    //alert(chart); 
  var options = {
      animationEnabled: true,
      data: [
      {
         type: "spline", //change it to line, area, column, pie, etc
         dataPoints: chart
      }                     ]
  }; 
  $("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart(options);
```

But when i try like this instead, it won't work:

```
 var parsed = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
 var counter = 0;
 var chart = []
 for (var i in parsed) 
 {
   counter++;
   var profit = parsed[i].Profit;
   chart.push({x: counter,y: profit});
 }

 var options = {
     animationEnabled: true,
     data: [
     {
         type: "spline", //change it to line, area, column, pie, etc
         dataPoints: chart
     }                   
     ]
     };
```

So i guess that array is not properly defined, counter and profit are 100% ok.

I need array like this:

```
  var chart = [{x: 1, y: 10}, {x: 2, y: 13}, {x: 3, y: 18}, {x: 4, y: 20}, {x: 5, y: 17},{x: 6, y: 10}, {x: 7, y: 13}, {x: 8, y: 18}, {x: 9, y: 20}, {x: 10, y: 17}];
```

In Console there are no errors, just chart is empty.

**FOUND SOLUTION:**

```
var profit = parseInt(parsed[i].Profit);
```

Comment: Please supply also the exact error message. Look into console (ctrl+shift+k in Firefox).

Comment: Console is empty, i don't have any error.

Answer (score 0):

A bit nicer than your code, using [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```
var options = {
    animationEnabled: true,
    data: [{
        type: "spline",
        dataPoints: $.map(parsed, function (i, item) {
            return {
                x: i + 1,
                y: +item.Profit;  // unary + causes type conversion to Number
            }
        })
    }]
};
```